# Assign docker container an external link through the API

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have an application which, among other thigns allows you to spin up docker containers  with custom running code with the help from an api, which is also dockerised.

So from the API container I do:

```
exec(`curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'{"Image": "botimage", "ExposedPorts": {"${PORT}/tcp": {"HostPort": "${PORT}"}}, "HostConfig": {"Binds": ["${dirPath}/bots/api/bots/strategies:/usr/src/bots/strategies", "${dirPath}/bots/api/database:/usr/src/bots/database", "${dirPath}/postgres/data:/usr/src/bots/data"], "NetworkMode": "bitmex_backend"}, "PortBindings": { "${PORT}/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "${PORT}" }] }, "Env": ["TOPIC=${TOPIC}","BOTNAME=${BOT_NAME}","EXEC_ENV=${EXEC_ENV}","BITMEX_KEYS=${BITMEX_KEYS}","TIME_FRAME=${TIME_FRAME}","PORT=${PORT}"], "Cmd": ["node", "app.js"]}\' -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/create?name=${BOT_NAME}`,
  (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return;
    }

    var id = JSON.parse(stdout).Id;
    //  Would this work with the name too? 
    logEvent(LOG_LEVELS.info, RESPONSE_CODES.LOG_MESSAGE_ONLY, `Initializing containerised strategy `)
    exec(`curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/${id}/start`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return;
      }
    });
  });
```

And it spins up a new container, again dynamically.

Im wonderin how I can bring this new container down from another container.

From localhost I can simply do:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/test/stop
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X DELETE http:/v1.24/containers/test
```

How ever when I try to do this from another docker container by:

```
exec(`curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/test/stop`)
exec(`curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X DELETE http:/v1.24/containers/test`)
```

I get the following error:

> { Error: Command failed: curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X
>   POST http:/v1.24/containers/test/stop curl: (7) Couldn't connect to
>   server
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:299:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)   killed: false,   code: 7,
> ```
>
> signal: null,   cmd:

I think getting something like this should be addressable with something like external_links done when im building the container.

Any idea on if this is the right call? or how I can tackle the issue? deff. looks like a networking problem.

Comment: Where do the variables like `PORT` and `dirPath` come from?  It seems like it'd be really easy to root the host with this.  (Never `exec('curl ...')` when you could just natively make an HTTP call; it's almost trivial to root the host if you have access to the Docker socket so be extra extra careful with basic security things.  If the caller controls `dirPath` then they can, for example, put a `;` in it to run multiple commands, and that could be bad.)

Comment: Agreed these specific ones are reaused through out, so I made them vars at the top of the file. Regardless this is a pet project not something that will go into production. Thanks for pointing it out though. Any ideas on the actual question?

Comment: Since the Docker socket is security-sensitive, it isn't made available to containers by default.  (Again, it's almost trivial to root the entire host if you can access the socket at all.)  A container can exit itself pretty easily (just exit the main process) but otherwise you might be better off having just a single orchestrator process and limiting access to the socket as much as you can.

Comment: Id really like to do this from one docker container to another. How would I go about 'rooting the entire host'.

Comment: `docker run -v /:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` for example would let you see the host's encrypted password file; you can see or edit any file you want, as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to let docker containers control other docker containers the way you are describing is to expose the docker socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) to the "controlling" container. You can do that like this:

```
darkstar:~$ docker run \
                  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \  
                  <my_image>
darkstar:~$ docker exec -u root -it <container id> /bin/bash
```

Now, as root inside the container, you can install docker CLI (This is not strictly necessary, depending on how you plan to manipulate docker from inside the container. Also, I am assuming a Debian-like Linux, YMMV):

```
root@guest:/# apt-get update
root@guest:/# apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
                                ca-certificates \
                                curl \
                                gnupg2 \
                                software-properties-common
root@guest:/# rel=$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")
root@guest:/# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/${rel}/gpg > /tmp/dkey
root@guest:/# apt-key add /tmp/dkey
root@guest:/# add-apt-repository \
             "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/${rel} \
              $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
root@guest:/# apt-get update
root@guest:/# apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

I would suggest doing a `docker commit` here (from the host, not in the container) to save the state of the image so you don't need to repeat the above steps every time a rebuild happens.

Now the container should have access to the socket:

```
root@guest:/# docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED       ...
69340bc13bb2        my_image              "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   8 minutes ago ...
```

Whether this is a good idea or not is debatable. I would suggest not doing this if there is any way to avoid it. It's a security hole that essentially throws out the window some of the main benefits of using containers: isolation and control over privilege escalation.